# Blender Collision Simulation Data

Tags: python, game-engine, physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

Is it possible to access data from a collision, such as point of collision and impact force? I am trying to simulate a "drop test" in Blender and cannot figure out how to access the information. As of now, I am trying to use the Blender game engine and python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using collision callbacks you can retrieve the hit object, point and normal (not sure about how to retrieve the impact force though). See the [API reference](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.collisionCallbacks) for more info. Example file below.

```py
def my_callback(object, point, normal):
    ''' Do whatever you want with your collision data '''
    print('Hit by', object.name, 'at', point, 'with normal', normal)

def register_callback(cont):
    ''' Run this with an always sensor (tap enabled) when the game starts '''
    own = cont.owner

    if not my_callback in own.collisionCallbacks:
        own.collisionCallbacks.append(my_callback)
```

[image]

Example file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to run this code while the game engine is running?

Comment: @RussellChow I've added a better script and a example file (for Blender 2.79). If this answers your question, please accept the answer. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!